# Get argument objects to work on underscore _.first function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

I have to recreate the Underscore **_.first function**, but I'm failing to make it work on argument objects. These are the tests it has to pass:

- should return an array with the first n elements of the array
- should return an array with the first element if n is not a number, is zero, or negative
- should return the entire array if n is > length
- should return an empty array if array is not an array
- **should work on an arguments object**

And this is what i have so far:

```
_.first = function (array, n) {

  var arr = [];

  if (!Array.isArray(array)) return arr;
  if (isNaN(n) || n == null || n <= 0) return array.slice(0,1);
  else return array.slice(0, n);
};
```

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What is meant by "arguments object"? That it should be able to return the n first properties of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
_.first = function (array, n) {

  if (array == null || array == undefined || array.length < 1) return [];
  array = Array.from(array);
  if (isNaN(n) || n == null || n <= 0) return array.slice(0,1);
  else return array.slice(0, n);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for

```
_.first = function (array, n) {
  if (!Array.isArray(array))
    array = Array.from(array);
  if (typeof n != "number" || isNaN(n) || n <= 0)
    n = 1;
  return array.slice(0, n);
};
```

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)  works on any object that is iterable or has a `.length` property, like `arguments`  objects do. However, the exercise reads like it wants you to implement an element-copying loop yourself, instead of calling `slice`, which would then trivially work on any array-like object.

Comment: this solves the problems, however after using it theres another test failing "should return an empty array if array is not an array" :/

Comment: @Ed.P Please don't edit different requirements into the question after answers were posted. Also, these tests are conflicting: an arguments object is not an array, so what should it do with them? Ask your instructor for clarification.

Answer (score -1):

If it should be able to return the `n` first entries in the case the argument is an object then something like this should work:

```
if (typeof array === 'object' && array !== null) {
   const obj = array;
   return Object.entries(obj).slice(0, n);
}
```